# Font bolder than expected Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <!-- Optional theme -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
         <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-nav">
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">This is some test text</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

That is my html

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}  

.sidebar-nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Open Sans", serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

That's my css

Applying the Open Sans font family to the **a** element changes the font but it looks bold, when it should be thinner.

I've tried other fonts as well and they all look bolder.

How it should be:
[image]

How it is (Here it looks more bubbly):

[image]

Update: https://jsfiddle.net/xzw2ssz5/

Comment: This is because of specificity. Share us what is overriding it? Can you show us a screenshot like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3YvE.png

Comment: On my side it´s working - https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/306/

Comment: yes same here, its working https://jsfiddle.net/mgd01a0x/

Comment: Let me post some screenshots, oh and it works if i use Serif, but Open Sans doesn't work :(

Comment: @user230485295 Try putting Open Sans `<link />` on the top?

Comment: Didn't work @PraveenKumar

Comment: When I zoomed in on the black background, there's also some sort of blue border around the font? what is that?

Comment: that looks like its a font-weight issue, not a font issue, have you checked to see if you bolded the font or set font-weight somewhere else?

Comment: That's the weird part, didn't apply font weight anywhere. That's all the code I used @Keith

Comment: then it might be bootstrap, have you tried setting .sidebar-nav ul li a { font-weight: normal }

Comment: @Keith tried that as well. Doesn't change anything. I also tried using other fonts and every font comes out bolder. It's so strange.

Comment: can you copy the exact code from your html into a jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xzw2ssz5/ @Keith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to paste the following code in your custom CSS file.

```
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans" !important;
}
```

And make sure that your fonts are properly being loaded by navigating to the `Network` tab in developer tools and then selecting the checking the fonts.

If you don't want to apply the fonts on the entire document then try putting `!important` in front of your `font-family` rule like so:

```
.sidebar-nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Open Sans", serif !important;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Let me know if that works for you.

**Update**

okay, I've got it up and running. Basically, you haven't selected any `font-weight` from the google fonts library. Replace your `<link>` with this one:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i" rel="stylesheet">
```

Keep the font-weights values which you want and remove all others. That's why you were not able to change its font-weight. Hope that helps now.

Comment: Change the `font-weight` property according to your own value. For example: `font-weight: 100 !important`. Try with `!important` for now. If it works then try removing it and checking it again. If the problem arises again then it means your custom styles are being loaded before bootstrap CSS

Comment: Can I help you out using Teamviewer or something?

Comment: okay, I've got it up and running. Basically you haven't selected any `font-weight` from the google fonts library. Replace your `<link>` with this one:
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think the problem is the order you're calling the your css resources

move the Open Sans import on top of your css stylesheet try this or just @import the css font directly into your stylesheet.

```
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" 
  type="text/css">
```

Comment: that is happening because you didn't specify the font weights when you imported from google and its automatically applying the 400 font weight default go back to google font and specify the font weights you want it should look something like this <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Yes, @RonnyPerez is right. If you don't  specify a value for `font-weight` yourself then the value `400` will be used by default.